# Hide a list element in html based on a php condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a navigation bar. 4 links.
There's a php variable x; It can have values 1,2 or 3.
if x equals 1; all links are shown.
If x equals 2; only link4 is shown.
If x equals 3; all links are hidden.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="link1.php"> link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.php"> link2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3.php">link3</a></li>   
<li><a href="link4.php">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

There's a simple way of doing this using if else.

```
if($x==1)
{
<li><a href="link1.php"> link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.php"> link2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3.php">link3</a></li>   
<li><a href="link4.php">link4</a></li>
} 
if($x==2)
{
<li><a href="link4.php">link4</a></li>
}
if($x==3) {  }
```

Well..This is simple. I like things a bit complicated. Is there any way to implement the same using Jquery or Javascript or something?

Comment: Why would you make your code complicated?

Comment: To learn new things. I want to know whether there is an other way of doing this. @Daan

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/czHQE/2/

Comment: No there isn't if you want it to be based on the value of a _PHP_ variable.

Comment: @Joseph there would be... eg: `<script type="text/javascript"> var x = <?php echo $x?></script>`

Comment: @TheJoker, please, check out my answer, it might help you.

Comment: Well. I thought my jokes were bad. Someone's not happy here... And you must be Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's squeeze. The task of learning something new isn't a bad thing. @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @TheJoker, you missed the point. You should not learn anything by complicating an easy task. You should solve more complicated tasks if you are looking for a challenge, but it seems that you are so green you have never met really complicated tasks or programming is just not for you. As about your statement about Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy is so ridiculous that I rather do not comment it, whoever he or she is.

Comment: There's a little fight in you. I like that. Doing complicated things in simple way is usual. I like everything complicated. You see...I am not a bad person. I am simply ahead of the curve. @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @TheJoker, programming is not about preferences. You are responsible in the direction of your boss/client who pays you good money to work for them and it is imperative, not optional to provide the best solution. If you complicate the code mentioned in your question, then you ruin the quality and clarity of your code. By worsening the quality of your code you are also worsening the quality of the product, thus making financial losses to people who trust you. By worsening the clarity of your code you are forcing your colleagues to spend more time studying it and your boss to pay for this waste

Comment: of time. This is immoral, irresponsible, impractical and selfish way of working, basically saying that "I like to make things more complicated, so everybody who relies on me should suffer, I don't care". With this philosophy you would not survive a day in my company. I understand you are still learning and you might be a bright fellow, but with such an attitude you have no future. If you want to challenge yourself, solve more complicated things. Essentially you are not ahead of the curve. Instead, you are lost in the woods. And it is really easy to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**test.php?x=**

```
<?php
$x = 1; //default
if(isset($_REQUEST['x']))
{
    $x = $_REQUEST['x'];
}
?>
<script src="jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var x = '<?php echo $x;?>';
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(x==2)
    {
        var i=0;
        $("#link li" ).each(function() {
            i+=1;
            if(i!=4)
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }   
        });
    }
    else if(x==3)
    {
        $("#link" ).hide();
    }

});
</script>
<ul id="link">
    <li><a href="link1.php"> link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.php"> link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.php">link3</a></li>   
    <li><a href="link4.php">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo :](http://jsfiddle.net/SCD6Y/)** for x=1

**[Demo :](http://jsfiddle.net/SCD6Y/1/)** for x=2

**[Demo :](http://jsfiddle.net/SCD6Y/2/)** for x=3

Comment: This is kinda great. The code looks much better.Thank YOU. @Satish Sharma

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is bad. It is never good to complicate things. You can of course complicate your code with AJAX requests, invisible iframes loading data or else. However, this is a BAD idea. You should conclude that you have successfully solved your problem and if you intend to find new challenges, start experimenting with tasks which are more complicated, but your instinct to simplify things (which will prove to be VERY useful) if you ask yourself and this community the bad questions. You should plan more features to your page and you will instantly find more difficult challenges without going into the wrong way of your self-building.

Comment: Well. I thought my jokes were bad. Someone's not happy here... And you must be Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's squeeze. The task of learning something new isn't a bad thing. @Lajos Arpad

Answer (score 0):

May be some spagetti code using a class to hide rows when not needed ?

```
<li class='<?php echo ($x == 1)? '':'hidden'; ?>'><a href="link1.php"> link1</a></li>
<li class='<?php echo ($x == 1)? '':'hidden'; ?>'><a href="link2.php"> link2</a></li>
<li class='<?php echo ($x == 1)? '':'hidden'; ?>'><a href="link3.php">link3</a></li>   
<li class='<?php echo ($x == 1 || $x == 2)? '':'hidden'; ?>'><a href="link4.php">link4</a></li>

<style>
   li.hidden{
       display:none;
   }
</style>
```

Instead of class you may use style instead of class:
`<li <?php echo ($x == 1)? "" : "style='display:none;'" ?> >`

Also a cleaner CSS + class scenario can be:

```
<li class='view<?php echo $x ?> row1" >...</li> 
<li class='view<?php echo $x ?> row2" >...</li> 
<li class='view<?php echo $x ?> row3" >...</li> 
<li class='view<?php echo $x ?> row4" >...</li> 

<style>
    li.view3{
       display:none;
    }
    li.view2{
       display:none;
    }
    li.view2.row4{
       display:block;
    }
    li.view1{
       display:block;
    }
</style>
```

The css is not otpimizzed here for more clarity.

Comment: What is this tag '<php'. Gotta be a mistake @d.raev

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really mean/why you'd even want to `implement the same using Jquery or Javascript or`.

I'd suggest just applying a CSS class selector instead, far easier to manipulate, maybe approach it in PHP like this:

```
$x = 1;

$links = array(
    'link1' => array(
        'show' => array(1)
    ),
    'link2' => array(
        'show' => array(1)
    ),
    'link3' => array(
        'show' => array(1)
    ),
    'link4' => array(
        'show' => array(1,2)
    ),
);

foreach ($links as $link => $details) {
    echo '<a href="' . $link .'.php" class="' . (in_array($x, $details['show']) ? '' : 'hidden') .'">' . $link . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uU4mk/4/)**

change the i value base on your scenario

```
      var i=2;  // change the value 

        showAndHideLi(i);  


         function showAndHideLi(val){
           var catch=$("ul li");

            if(val==1){

                catch.show();        
            }
               else if(val==2){

                  catch.hide(); 
                  catch.eq(3).show();

               }
                 else if(val==3){

                  catch.hide();    
                 }


        }
```

Comment: @TheJoker If you seems that this answer has helped you, then please try to accept this as your answer./

Comment: OK. I will use this answer. I am a man of my words. @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @TheJoker No.. i just asked you to click on the tick mark available on the left top portion of this answer.. :)

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy. I like the other answer. So I accept that.